# Why volume mapping does not work?

Tags: docker

I need to run a npm commands via a dockerized npm as:

```
$ docker run -it -v /C/Users/sam/Documents/Workspace/project:/workspace lynxsolutions/docker-npm-bower-gulp /bin/bash
```

The image name is: lynxsolutions/docker-npm-bower-gulp

I will have the prompt:

```
root@892f74a14e2d:/workspace#
```

however, if I run ls, it will return nothing, so, why the volume mapping is not working?

Comment: Does this path exist and contains files in the host machine? You specify docker command with Windows-style path, Is it properly declared?

Comment: Yes,the path is right, and when i try to give him the path in windows-style like this: `C:\Users\sam\Documents\Workspace\project` it give me this error `docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid bind mount spec "C:\\Users\\sam\\Documents\\Workspace\\project:/workspace": volumeinvalidmode: invalid mode: "/workspace"`

Comment: But I assume you're using docker machine or virtualbox in some manner to run Docker?

Comment: Yes i use docker toolbox and vm to run my project.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing capitalization on /C, i.e. use /c.

Answer (score -1):

You are running docker using Windows, together with tools like Docker toolbox, or simply a VM to manage your docker containers.
All your volumes and files you wish to share with your container must reside on the host machine, the one that is actually running the docker daemon, that is, in your case, the VM

Hence, You cannot create a volume with files that resides on your computer, as they aren't accessible from within the host (the VM)
You would have to first copy the files to the VM, to some location and then use that location as the host mountpoint

Comment: But, I need to create a volume, not to copy the files .. I already created volumes using docker-compose , but running the image directly didn't work..